# Factory reset of OpenWrt router, are my sensitive config files really not recoverable after command "firstboot"?

Tags: deletion, openwrt

I would like to give away an old OpenWrt router. I have done the following.

```
firstboot -y && reboot
/dev/ubi0_1 is mounted as /overlay, only erasing files
Connection to 192.168.55.12 closed by remote host.
```

Is this really safe, can my config files not be restored? I don't really trust this command because it was done way too fast.

If this command does not safely delete the config files, how can I do this (without damaging the OpenWrt installation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this really safe, can my config files not be restored? I don't really trust this command because it was done way too fast.

First of all, the time it takes is irrelevant. It's a small amount of data, and depending on the type of memory overwriting is done in a single cycle - on the order of nanoseconds or milliseconds.

Second, if it's enough *really* depends on the nitty gritty details - both of the device, and to what lengths an attacker is willing to go to. If someone is willing to desolder the memory chips and interface them directly, without ever powering up the device, the chance of recovery is bigger than if interfacing the memory chips from OpenWRT.

Second, how the device handles memory is relevant. Is it flash that is TRIM'd? or is it flash that is only erased when overwritten?

In short, to be secure, you should rotate any secrets that was written to the storage of the device. In practice, for a home user setup, I would not bother.